# Playing Video On External Monitor With Java

Tags: java, media

The problem I am trying to solve is playing a video streamed online to a laptop, and then having the laptop play it on HDMI/VGA connected monitor.

Are there any good libraries tutorials in Java for doing this? Or is there a better cross platform language to accomplish this?

Comment: JavaFX can do this, using the [Screen](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html) and [MediaView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) classes.